# Time Taken to create memory snapshot in YourKit Format on a 8GB JVM

Tags: java, jvm, profiler, yourkit

Does anyone know how much time would it take to capture memory snapshot of a 8GB heap size Java 1.6 JVM in YourKit format? And will it completely halt JVM during that time?

I want to find methods that are creating excessive garbage and thus want to enable object allocation recording and then take memory snapshot in YourKit format.

Thanks,
Sameer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Snapshot captuting time depends on your hadrware (amount of RAM, I/O speed). It might take several minutes.

2) Profiler completely pauses JVM.